# Stringify a JSON object with the property name in uppercase using stringify and replace

Tags: javascript, json, function, replace, stringify

I have to complete this function, how i can replace name of property with its corresponding name in upper case.

```
function stringify(v){

  function replacer(k,v){
    // to be completed
  }

  return JSON.stringify(v,replacer)
}

console.log(stringify(JSON.parse(process.argv[2])))
```

For instance, the command:

> node json_upper_case.js '[{"city":"Milano","Air Quality":"red","Temperature":10},{"air quality":"yellow","Temperature":20,"Sea conditions":3,"City":"Genova"}]'

is expected to print the following output:

> [{"CITY":"Milano","AIR QUALITY":"red","TEMPERATURE":10},{"AIR QUALITY":"yellow","TEMPERATURE":20,"SEA CONDITIONS":3,"CITY":"Genova"}]

Comment: Please show your attempt. We are here to guide you to the right path, not to help you complete your work.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: yes but i'm newer on js, I understand that initially, the replacer function is called with an empty string as key representing the object being stringified. It is then called for each property on the object or array being stringified
but I was able to change only the name of the property values:

Answer (score 0):

A simple `Array.prototype.map()` along with some dynamic property name access does the job:

```js
let json = `[{
  "city": "Milano",
  "Air Quality": "red",
  "Temperature": 10
}, {
  "air quality": "yellow",
  "Temperature": 20,
  "Sea conditions": 3,
  "City": "Genova"
}]`

function keysToUppercase(j) {
  if (typeof j === 'string') { // so it works for javascript arrays as well
    try {
      j = JSON.parse(j);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Invalid JSON input');
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
  j = j.map(x => {
    for (let prop in x) {
      x[prop.toUpperCase()] = x[prop];
      delete x[prop];
    }
    return x;
  })
  return j;
}

console.log(keysToUppercase(json));
```

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter shows almost the right answer, try to modify the given function to fit your needs:

```
function replacer(key, value) {
  // Filtering out properties
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return undefined;
  }
  return value;
}
```